# How to use onClick in imported .map() react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok so I have two files Test.js and Test2.js

Test.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const hello = ['hello', 'hi', 'sup'];

export const helloWorld = hello.map(helloCode => {
  return (
    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{helloCode}</button>
  );
});
```

Test2.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { helloWorld } from './Test';

export class RealTest extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked');
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
           {helloWorld}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I can't figure out how to get helloWorld to access the onClick function, I have tried to create a props, I have tried binding it, but I cannot get it to work unless it is in Test2.js, but I need it to be in it's own seperate file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not put `helloWorld` and `hello` in the actual component?

Comment: I am going to have multiple .map() that I will need to put in separate files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adam suggesting passing the context down, but I think it's more React like to pass props.

```
export const HelloWorld = props => hello.map(helloCode => {
  return (
    <button 
      key={helloCode} // <--- make sure to add a unique key
      onClick={props.handleClick}
    >
      {helloCode}
    </button>
  );
});
```

Then render:

```
 <div>
    <HelloWorld handleClick={this.handleClick} />
 </div>
```

Comment: It's throwing an error where it says that I cannot use uppercase html in react when I render it like this <helloWorld handleClick={this.handleClick} />

Comment: Make sure to use uppercase `<HelloWorld ..` here's working code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cb82at

Comment: What if I had multiple .map() functions that I wanted to put into a class?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you mean you want one component to display several lists?

Answer (score 0):

The array of JSX accessed via the variable `helloWorld` does not have any knowledge of what you want the context (e.g. `this`) to be when it's in it's own file (and, thus, `this.handleClick` can't be used).

The simplest way is to make it a function so you can pass the correct context:

```
import React from 'react';

const hello = ['hello', 'hi', 'sup'];

export const helloWorld = (context) => hello.map(helloCode => {
  return (
    <button onClick={context.handleClick}>{helloCode}</button>
  );
});
```

and then in your render method, pass in the context:

```
render() {

    return (
      <div>
           {helloWorld(this)}
      </div>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hello = ['hello', 'hi', 'sup'];

const HelloWorld = (props) => <div>{hello.map(name =>(<button onClick={() => props.handleClick(name)}>{name}</button>))}</div>


class RealTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(name) {
    console.log('clicked for name ', name);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
           <HelloWorld handleClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <RealTest/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: no need for the extra div. even if you wanted to be react 15, you could use an `<Aux />` component https://github.com/gajus/react-aux

Comment: you can use `React.Fragment` as well :) div added to group them. `Fragment` will not require you to install any npm pkg though!

Comment: you're missing `key`

Comment: yes but if you have `Fragment` then you also have array components

Comment: `Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM` ... what do you mean by "have array components" ?

Comment: Fragments were introduced in React 16, which also added returning an array from components. So before React 16 `<Aux />` was what Fragment is now.

Comment: I was saying about adding `div` to wrap buttons. My comment on your answer code is different, you are returning `.map` result directly which will not work before `v16`